# Is it good coding practice to exit a switch statement by calling a function with no intent to return

Tags: c, switch-statement

C newbie question. I have inherited C code that uses a switch statement to call functions as a means of exiting the switch. The called functions are not intended to return back into the switch statement unless there is POR or an access violation. The code after the switch is a while(1){} loop to prevent code run away (I guess).

Is this good coding practice? It seems that it if downstream code continues using functions to branch it would clutter the stack. Is there a better way to break out of switch statement when there is no intention to return afterwards?

The code works. However in website example code the switch statement is usually embedded in a while(1) loop where it is intended for the function to return to the switch statement.

```
switch(SYSRSTIV)
     {
     case SYSRST_NMIRST:
         reset_funtion(); //initialize hardware
         do_something1(); 
         break;
     case SYSRST_WDTPW:  
         pw_violation(); //Watchdog violation
         do_something2();
         break;
     case SYSRST_BOR:
         do_something3(); //normal operation
         break;
     default:
         do_something3();
      }


 while(1){ //trap if fall through
     set_error_flag();

 }
}
```

Comment: If you use the C11 [_Noreturn](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Noreturn) keyword or gcc/clang `__attribute__((noreturn))` with the declarations for functions that will never return, your compiler can optimize things to use less stack space, btw.

Comment: thanks Shawn! I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine as long as you don't arrive at this very switch statement recursively and create infinite recursion. There's nothing special about the switch statement why you couldn't call an infinite loop from it.

Though having a single main loop and running the switch every iteration might result in more easily understandable code.

Comment: Thanks Krisz. It felt that the original code author was using the do_something functions in leu of "goto"  statement. Is there a way to branch in C code without a function call that might be more appropriate in the above example?

Comment: A function call doesn't do branching, only if it is a function pointer.

Comment: @kial Please don't worry about the lack of a `goto`, either in the C source or in the generated assembly.  Use Shawn's suggestion about 'noreturn'; that might help. And don't worry about "cluttering the stack" -- truly, this isn't generally a problem, and especially not in this case.  A `switch` statement and a bunch of function calls is fine.